# How to add tracing code to webpack modules

Tags: typescript, webpack, next.js

I want to understand why our next.js code has a long cold boot on vercel / aws. I would love to add a console.time and console.endTime call before / after each module that webpack has built. For example:

```js
/***/ 25173:
/***/ ((__unused_webpack_module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) => {

console.time(`src/client/useLaunchpads.ts`)  // <-- My injected tracing code

"use strict";
/* harmony export */ __webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, {
/* harmony export */   "D": () => (/* binding */ useLaunchpads)
/* harmony export */ });
/* harmony import */ var _client_useFeatureFlag__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ = __webpack_require__(80501);
/* harmony import */ var _client_useTeam__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__ = __webpack_require__(78007);
/* harmony import */ var _utils_api__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__ = __webpack_require__(65572);



const useLaunchpads = ({ includeGlobal  })=>{
    const { teamId  } = (0,_client_useTeam__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__/* .useTeam */ .t)();
    const featureFlag = (0,_client_useFeatureFlag__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__/* .useFeatureFlag */ .ye)("launchpads");
    const { data: launchpads  } = _utils_api__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__/* .api.launchpad.getByTeam.useQuery */ .h.launchpad.getByTeam.useQuery({
        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion
        teamId: teamId,
        includeGlobal
    }, {
        enabled: !!teamId && featureFlag?.isEnabled
    });
    return {
        launchpads
    };
};

console.timeEnd(`src/client/useLaunchpads.ts`) // <-- My injected tracing code

/***/ }),
```

I experimented with a webpack Plugin and tried to access the modules in `compilation.hooks.seal`, `compiler.hooks.make` or `compilation.hooks.processAssets` and change the modules source. But I get `SyntaxError: Unexpected token` or other errors.

I think I need to use another webpack hook but I don't know which one. We use typescript and I want to measure how long requiring other modules take. So ideally my injected code would be after the ts -> js compilation.

Here is my current code:

```js
'use strict'

const { ConcatSource } = require('webpack-sources')

class TestPlugin {
  apply(compiler) {
    compiler.hooks.compilation.tap('TestPlugin', (compilation) => {
      compilation.hooks.seal.tap(
        'TestPlugin',
        (module) => {
          compilation.modules.forEach((module) => {
            const path = module?.resource // Getting the path of original file
            if (!path || path.includes('node_modules')) return
            if (module._source && path.includes('useLaunchpads')) {
              // console.log('module._source', module._source)
              module._source = new ConcatSource(
                // `console.time('${1}');`,
                // '\n',
                '/*This is a test*/ ',
                '\n',
                module._source.source()
                // '\n',
                // `console.timeEnd('${1}');`
              )
            }
          })
        }
      )
    })
  }
}

module.exports = TestPlugin
```

Result:

```
- info Creating an optimized production build ./Users/sean/dev/teampilot/.next/server/chunks/5286.js:3262
e  /utils/api";
             ^^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1178:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1220:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at __webpack_require__.f.require (/Users/sean/dev/teampilot/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:236:28)
    at /Users/sean/dev/teampilot/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:154:40

> Build error occurred
```